# Can the code to this problem statement be made smaller?

Tags: python, sorting, partitioning

[The problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeXRe.png)

My solution is given below, I tried it by splitting all the possible lists and then joining the same again. Somewhere I felt it was much lengthier.

> ```
> cake=list(input().strip())
> string=[]
> capstring=[]
> evnum=[]
> oddnum=[]
>
> for x in range(0,len(cake)):
>     if str(cake[x]).isdigit():
>         if int(cake[x])%2==0:
>             evnum.append(cake[x])
>         else: oddnum.append(cake[x])
>     else:
>         if str(cake[x]).isupper():
>             capstring.append(cake[x])
>         else: string.append(cake[x])
>         
> sort_evnum=sorted(evnum)
> sort_oddnum=sorted(oddnum)
> sort_string=sorted(string)
> sort_capstring=sorted(capstring)
>
> final_evnum=''.join(sort_evnum)
> final_oddnum=''.join(sort_oddnum)
> final_string=''.join(sort_string)
> final_capstring=''.join(sort_capstring)
>
> print(final_string+final_capstring+final_oddnum+final_evnum)
> ```

Comment: List comprehension can help reduce the SLOC.

Comment: Please include your problem statement _as text_, not as a screenshot

Answer (score 3):

A simple appropriate [sort key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) will do:

```
def sort_key(c):
    return (c.isdigit(), c.isupper(), c.isdigit() and not int(c) % 2, c)

def my_sort(s):
    return ''.join(sorted(s, key=sort_key))

>>> my_sort("Sorting1234")
'ginortS1324'
```

The sort key makes use of the fact that `False` ( `== 0`) comes before `True` ( `== 1`) and that tuples are sorted lexicographically (first non-equal element decides). So the returned tuple will order:

- non-digits before digits (`c.isdigit()`)
- lower before upper (`c.isupper()`)
- odd before even (`not int(c) % 2`)
- alphabetically (`c` itself)

Comment: For ASCII strings: `(c < 'a', c < 'A', c in '02468', c)`